# .net, built in way to get directory name from path?

Tags: .net

Given the following directory:

```
string fullpath = "C:\MyDir1\MyDir2\MyDir3";
```

I would like to return "MyDir3" - this being the directory name (not full path, of a directory) , I know I can do this using string manipulation, but is there an easy (built in way) to achieve this using framework classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
string dir = new DirectoryInfo(fullpath).Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
string s =new  System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyDir1\MyDir2\MyDir3").Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@"C:\MyDir1\MyDir2\MyDir3")
```